# How do I make listing from "Listing 1:" to "1. listing."

Tags: captions, listings

Now, by default listing package produces listing names like:

```
Listing 1: some text
```

How do I make it to produce names like:

```
1 listing. Some text
```

Package:

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

I guess it should be something like:

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\arabic{???} listing.}
```

Usage:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,caption={caption},captionpos=b,label={lst:label}]
Some code
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy with the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{reversed}{#2.\bothIfSecond{~}{#1}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  labelformat = reversed ,
  labelsep = period
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Test]
  a b c
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You should ensure that the caption of the listings and those of figures and tables and possibly other floats have the same setup. It's easy: just use `\captionetup` without the optional argument:

```
\captionsetup{
  labelformat = reversed ,
  labelsep = period
}
```

Comment: Nice and thanks! How do I also get rid of colon punctuation mark? Like "1. Listing. Test"

Comment: @RendoJack I edited the answer